# Adding repositories with “./”

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository

I'm trying to add [this unoficcial repository](http://debian.holoscopio.com/sltv/) to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine (32 bits), in order to install a software called SLTV. [According to the official site](https://wiki.softwarelivre.org/TV/ProjetoSLTV#Instala_o_a_partir_do_reposi_AN1), the following lines should be used:

```
deb http://debian.holoscopio.com/sltv/ ./
deb-src http://debian.holoscopio.com/sltv/ ./
```

If I add manually these 2 lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or to a new file in `etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) and then run apt-get update, I get an error message -- I'm not at work now, so I can't provide the exact error, but I can edit this post to include the message tomorrow.

I noticed the repository lines in the above example don't have the "main/stable/whatever" arguments. I'm not exactly sure what they mean. I'm guessing it's related to the distro release and to the machine architecture.

From what I see on other repositories and packages such as dropbox, the line `deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu karmic main` are a reference to the `http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/` folder.

But on this particular repository of the first example, the `Packages.gz` file is on the `sltv` folder. I'm guessing this is the reason for the `./` in the repository line. And I'm guessing this being in the repository line is the reason for the error.

My questions are:

1. Are my guesses wrong or correct?
2. In either case, how to proceed?

Comment: This question has been on askubuntu for a week with no votes and no answers, so I deleted it from there and re-asked it here.

Comment: With a trailing slash in the third column, apt looks for `http://debian.holoscopio.com/sltv/./Release` and so on, which is correct for this repository. Without a slash, apt looks for e.g. `http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/Release`. The repository works for me, by the way. Please copy-paste the error messages.

Comment: @Gilles sorry for taking your time. I tried the same proccess today and it worked fine. I don't know where I messed up previously. I'm so ashamed.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Maybe there was just a transient network error, or similar. Please feel free to close the question.

Comment: @derobert How do I properly close it?

Comment: @ruda.almeida I think there should be a close link right under the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same process now and it worked fine.

I can't figure out what was wrong before, but it was either a remote issue or some mistake by the user (me).

I have confirmed (and others confirm in comments), **having `./` in a sources.list file is a valid syntax**, at least in ubuntu 12.04.